# Where can I found beer's logos / labels in good image quality?

Tags: breweries

I'm making a Beer APP for mobile phones but I need a way to get good quality beer label for specific beers. So far, I'm using this free Beer's Api Service:

[BreweryDB.com](http://www.brewerydb.com/)

But as you can see, the quality of images is not so good:

[Heineken Dutch Dark (sample label)](http://www.brewerydb.com/beer/JMNBpw)

Is there another free service where I can found good quality beer's labels/logos?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, there isn't a central place where you can find high quality beer or wine labels. Sometimes you can find them at the brewery's website or an app like Untappd. But in general nobody has aggregated those labels. You would also run into intellectual property issue since many labels contain unique art work and you must get permission to reproduce. I know in the wine industry, people stopped putting high quality labels online because they were being downloaded in China and fake wine was being labeled as such.